# VSTS Hosted agents state

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am wondering how VSTS hosted agents provisioning works in terms of state. Does a hosted agent get reassigned from one job to another without being  'snapshotted' back to a 'clean' state? Or does it carry around the remnants from previous builds?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "'snapshotted' back to a 'clean' state"? If you haven't bought additional Hosted pipelines, the Hosted agent will build jobs one by one. And for when and how Hosted agent build jobs, it depends on when and how you trigger your build definition(s).

Comment: I realised I had an assumption here, which I haven't written. I am assuming that a hosted agent finishes one build and moves on to another. So my question was, will the same hosted agent run build for one VSTS subscription and then potentially another VSTS subscription.  If so, is it cleaned back to a 'clean' state so there is no data 'leakage' between subscriptions.

Comment: There won't has any data 'leakage' between subscriptions to use Hosted agent, even you build the same build definition for twice, you can not get ant data from first build to second build. That's why Clean option is not relevant when you use Hosted agent (As the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent reminder "Cleaning is not relevant if you are using a hosted agent because you get a new agent every time in that case").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't has any data 'leakage' between different subscriptions to use Hosted agent, even you build the same build definition for twice, you can not get any data from first build to second build.

That's why Clean option is not relevant when you use Hosted agent, and you can find [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent) section:

> **Note**
>
> Cleaning is not relevant if you are using a hosted agent because you
>   get a new agent every time in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Hosted agents are single-use only. They are not reused between builds.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, is there any documentation around this are that you could point me towards?